# Is user in dialout group?

Tags: bash

In my script I need to find out whether user is in dialout group and if he is not, add him to the group. I have found out how to add him but is there a way how to know if he is in the group ?

Comment: This isn't really a bash question. It does, however, depend on your operating system. (OS X? FreeBSD? NetBSD? Solaris? Some distro of Linux?) Please add more detail to your question, there isn't enough information provided for a complete answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in both ways:

- Check all groups a specific user is member of and check if `dialout` is there:

  ```
  id username
  ```

  Or as Wolf said already:

  ```
  groups username
  ```
- Check all members of the specific group (`dialout`) and check if the user is in the list:

  ```
  getent group dialout
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `groups` command.  Here's an example of me using it on a server I just happened to be talking to at the moment (I'm logged in as the `lprod` user):

```
[lprod@milazgit01 ~] $ groups wolf
wolf : prod tools
```

Then you can compare that to a regular expression in whatever shell you are using.